# Setting up github repository with jenkins

Tags: github, jenkins

I would like to know the steps to add a github repository to jenkins server.It will be really helpful if someone could suggest a manual.

Thanks and regards,
Newbie_in

Comment: There's already a Git plugin in the default installation. Is it a public or private repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to install the these plugins:

- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin
- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin

The former will enable you to check out code from at git repository by providing a URL and credentials.

The latter will enable you to configure hooks and more between from and jenkins (e.g. trigger a build automatically on push to a branch).